# Keeping a ratio column that's the division between two other columns

Tags: programming-practices, sql, patterns-and-practices

I'm about to build a SQL table where I want to store currency orders. That means that I need to store how much I paid for a certain quantity, and the ratio between both quantities. So for example:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| Quantity US | Quantity EUR | Ratio |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
|         250 |          200 | 1.25  |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

My question is: does it make sense to have a column storing a value that's always going to be the division between two columns, or is it a better practice to **not** store that in the DB and instead do the calculations every time I need the ratio?

Comment: Are there rounding steps or other complications involved in the exchange rate calculation, or can you actually guarantee that `Ratio = US / EUR` exactly in all cases no matter what? I could see a point to this if it's the former.

Comment: Do the quantities ever change once they're written?

Comment: @RobbieDee They're not meant for it, but both `Quantity US` and `Quantity EUR` are user inputted so I guess that's another point in favor for not creating the extra column, since it makes sense that users may need to fix a previous typo.

Comment: You should really ask this at dba.stackexchange.com.  There are 4 answers and not one person has mentioned that every bit of CPU you use costs exorbitantly more than a bit of storage (at least in SQL Server).  They're called *data*bases, not calculators.  Given, this is a tiny amount of CPU so you're probably fine with whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't look like it makes sense - the calculation is simple, quick and easily made in application code (or even in SQL).

Adding the column means the storage for it is required, IO costs go up etc... Which is one cost/benefit analysis you need to make here.

If the calculation were something highly CPU intensive, denormalizing as you describe could make sense, in particular if you need to sort by this column.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

A bit of redundancy is allowed if comes with measured performance benefits. And this is if and only if you really need that performance boost, aka if it's a bottleneck in your application.

So is it really that difficult to compute the ratio in your code? In your specific example I don't feel like the additional redundancy is justifiable. In my experience it's very rare to have a good reason to add redundant columns.

In conclusion, from what I read in your question, no, you shouldn't add that column. Though I may not know the whole story.

Also, as others have mentioned, you can always use [computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) ([in MySQL called generated columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/)) if you're really set on solving this in the database.

Comment: If you must have these available in the DB then computed columns are the way to go. They add no storage overhead and (most likely) will only be calculated when required by the query. Be careful of three-state logic, however, and calculation exceptions which may cause the session to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind it isn't really data that needs to be stored. If you *did* store it of course, there is the complication that the ratio would need to be re-calculated should any of the underlying values change. Whatever way you do this will be messy - be it with stored procedures or triggers etc.

You don't say how this fits into the system overall but you could just derive the column for a standard [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) scenario in the read SP or perhaps create a [view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) to calculate it on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Ratio is a derived column that can be calculated. Store the value in database **only** for performance reasons. If your queries are slow. Otherwise do not store the derived column in the database.

If you are not going to store the value in the database, which seems the most reasonable in your case, I recommend the following two options:

**1. If the calculation is simple you can use a view :**

> CREATE VIEW orders_view AS
>
> SELECT QtyUS, QtyEU, QtyUS/QtyEU Ratio
>
> FROM orders

**2. If the calculation is complex you can use a view and a stored procedure :**

> CREATE VIEW orders_view AS
>
> SELECT QtyUS, QtyEU, GetRatio(QtyUS,QtyEU) Ratio
>
> FROM orders

If the value must be stored in the database, I highly recommend using insert/update database triggers for updating the derived column. This way you will ensure 100% correctness of data.